# How does SE define the edits in editor list?

Tags: support, users-page

I see how many edits the users have in [editor list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors). How does SE define the edits in editor list? And how does SE sort the users who have the same number of edits?

Comment: @PatrickHofman The link you gave me answer part of my question. The link just points out the difference between the count used for strunk & white and the count on the editors tab.  And I want to know what kind of edits are counted in editor list and how does SE sort the users who have the same number of edits. Could you answer me?

Comment: To be sure got get am answer, what is the "editor list" you mention? Can you link to it?

Comment: You mean this one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors

Comment: Yes. I added a link to it.

Comment: I edited the answer on the other question to make it whole, now it's a full dupe. /cc @Pat

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks. I have seen it. Could you answer my another question which is how does SE sort the users who have the same number of edits?